# How to inject html code using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a tag that I want to inject some html code... ...the html code is like this...

> ```
> line:1   3spaces b4&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;line:3     5spaces
> ```
>
> b4<br />     5spaces b4, line: 4

If I use .text inject this code, it just shows text, but not the html code. I would like to convert it to a html code, how can I do so?? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it,

I need have a var htmlCode first, to convert it to decode HTML code, and use the html function... ... Thank everyone.

```
var htmlCode = $("<p/>").html("line:1   3spaces b4&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;line:3     5spaces b4&lt;br /&gt;     5spaces b4, line: 4").text();

$("#aaa").html(htmlCode);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: but using .html, I only can show this:

line:1 3spaces b4<br /><br />line:3 5spaces b4<br /> 5spaces b4, line: 4

Answer (score 6):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#divname').html("code");
```